# How to input foreign unicode characters into XeLaTeX?

Tags: unicode, latex, fonts, xelatex

Friends,

I am working on a XeLaTeX document. I am almost done with my document, but I need to input text from a foreign language. I am running Mac OS X. I go to Preferences > Language & Text and in there I enable Gurmukhi - QWERTY. This allows me to input Punjabi characters, which I am able to see in MS Word. I want to input the following unicode characters:

```
ਰੋਂਦਾ ਬੱਚਾ  ਿੲਕ
```

However, when I simply paste it into my TeXworks file, it simply does not show up when I compile a PDF file. I have indeed tried to google this, but came up with nothing other than adding some of these statements to my preamble. I am pretty desperate at this point.

My preamble already looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} %options: [a4paper, leqno, 11pt]
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[cm-default]{fontspec}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% -----Page Style-------------
\pagestyle{plain}

% -----Symbols----------------

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The characters are correct, but the CM fonts do not contain the glyphs. You need to select an OpenType font that contains Gurmukhi glyphs, and I think you have to explicitly choose the font when you need it. On Mac you can use “Gurmukhi MT” like this:

```
\newfontfamily\gu{Gurmukhi MT}
\begin{document}
{\gu ਰੋਂਦਾ ਬੱਚਾ  ਿੲਕ}
```

(FreeSans and FreeSerif also contain the glyphs.)

Also: The `inputenc` package warns that it should not be loaded as XeTeX already uses UTF8.